# Prevent multiple deletion proposals of the same topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I flagged a documentation topic for deletion, as it was a duplicate of a topic created earlier. A fellow user proposed deletion of the topic, acting on my flag. Few hours later another user proposed deletion of the topic, independent from my flag (although I'm unsure whether deletion without a flag is possible at all). Now both proposed changes are waiting for approval:

[image: first proposed change]

[image: second proposed change]

I suggest that subsequent changes that attempt to delete a topic should not be submitted, rather the user should be informed of the existing deletion proposal. We already have enough conflicting changes as it is, at least deletions of the same thing shouldn't interfere with each other.

Comment: so, what would happen if we have a deletion proposal and a proposal trying to improve the content?

Comment: @bwoebi nothing? I'm talking about two proposals, both suggesting deletion. We can still keep a single deletion proposal, along with non-deletion proposals.

Comment: Right, but then we still have conflicts… I'm trying to point out, that it's actually part of a major problem.

Comment: @bwoebi OK, I didn't quite get that. I'm not saying that this would solve all conflicts (it would most certainly not), but I don't see how it makes sense for multiple deletions to queue for approval instead of the same people voting on the same single proposal.

Comment: Funny, the same user that suggested the deletion also rejected the change http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/30117, btw your request was heard by the powers that meant to be.

Comment: Next time you flag this kind of stuff because is already covered in another topic you should include the topic link too, I had to go to "all topics" tab to verify.

Comment: I had this happen where I deleted an example, and another person did so afterwards but got approved before me, so I got rejected.

Comment: @Braiam thanks, I indeed should've linked to the dupe; but this was my first (and hasty) flagging on docs and simply screwed up:) (and realized a second too late) Sorry for the inconvenience.